# Almost Olympic bar -- collars don't fit

Tags: barbell

I obtained an almost Olympic sized bar -- all my plates fit on but none of my collars do (I have the spring kind). Where or how can I get collars to fit it?

Comment: Pictures would help.

Comment: The bar is a Farmer's Walk bar. From scouring the Internet, I found a suggestion to use spring clamps, available at almost every hardware store cheaply.

Comment: As in, you're using spring clamps and that solved the problem, or you're using spring clamps and it's still a problem?

Comment: I just bought the clamps, they fit, and a "test drive" worked fine. I'll consider it solved after a few workouts with them.

Comment: @portabella Consider self-answering the question if you've found something that works for you.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is localised to your own equipment.